# Firebase MacOS 11 Support

Tags: swift, macos, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Does Firestore informally support MacOS 11?

If so where are these resources?

I found other S.O. answers on Firestore about MacOS – but none which discuss MacOS 11.

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear about what you're tryign to do that requires macos support.  Firebase has over a dozen individual products with different SDKs and capabilities.

Comment: Fair. Just modified the question to solely ask about Firestore

Comment: As of the 8.9.0 release, Firebase has official beta support for macOS

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not have any Macos native libraries.  On all platforms that do not have native support, you can use the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) to directly read and write documents.

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries) for a comprehensive list of what is supported..

Answer (score 0):

Both Firebase Real Time Database as well as Firestore work on macOS.

We use it daily and in fact most of the coding answers we post here on SO come from macOS apps.

Firebase dropped official support for macOS at version 3, much to the chagrin of all of us desktop developers. Fortunately there is [community support](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk#community-supported-efforts) for it.

If you want to give it a spin, here's a podfile for 10.14 and above

```
project 'YourFirestoreProject.xcodeproj'

platform :osx, '10.14'

target 'YourFirestoreProject.xcodeproj' do
   use_frameworks!

   pod 'Firebase' #probably no longer needed
   pod 'Firebase/Auth'
   pod 'Firebase/Database'
   pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
   pod 'Firebase/Storage'
   pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
end
```

Something to keep in mind is that iOS and macOS app loading sequence is different. You'll need to initialize Firebase in viewDidLoad instead of the appDelegate. Other than that, it works.

There's a huge market for Handoff style applications and we sure wish Firebase were on that bandwagon and officially support macOS in their SDK